# Android animation flash vs. HTML5 vs. Android's native animation library?

Tags: java, android, flash, html, css

I am going to be writing a tower defense game for Android phones. I have knowledge of Java and the Android SDK; however, I am new to animation and have a few questions about where to start.

I will be using only 2D graphics (maybe later down the road 3D graphics but for now I will keep it simple), have basic animations (enemies moving along pre-determined paths, stationary towers shooting at moving enemies, and maybe a few explosions here and there), and some sounds that result from different in game actions. Just to give you a rough idea of what I am thinking about, my game would be very similar to [bloons tower defense 4](http://ninjakiwi.com/Games/Tower-Defense/Play/Bloons-Tower-Defense-4.html).

My question is, based on what I have stated above would you suggest I incorporate Flash, HTML5, or Android's native animation libraries? What are the pros and cons of using each one? If none of these are good options than what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using Android's native libraries. Adobe has already said they're not longer going to support flash on Android so you'll slowly users over time. And beside, Android's native libraries are going to give you better performance anyway. In addition, there are some really nice frameworks out there that make developing games on android with OpenGL super easy (see [andengine](http://www.andengine.org/) or this [Gamers post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-there-any-2d-gaming-libraries-frameworks-engines-for-android) for more details).

As far as HTML5 goes, I'd say stay away from it. Most users prefer a native app over a web-app and I can almost guarantee you that you're going to get better performance with a native app.

Comment: Thanks!, looks like I will be diving into Android's animation library shortly :)

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are going to make games, use definitely the **Java**. It is fast, there are plenty of game physic libraries, you can use OpenGL and you can even use C ports of some famous game libraries. You are simply not limited.

2) The **HTML5** is pretty slow so far and no matter how good it is for mobile web pages, it is not sufficient for more complex games then Tetris or Sudoku. Just try some HTML games on couple of Android devices - nothing is better then own experience.

3) Do not start with **Flash** - Adobe company closes the Flash support in mobile phones. See [there](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/nov/09/adobe-flash-mobile-dead) or [there](http://blog.gsmarena.com/adobe-stops-development-on-flash-player-for-mobile-browsers-focuses-on-html5/). This is releted to the Flash support in browsers.

4) As mentioned in one comment below - the **Adobe AIR** is other possibility and different story then Flash in web browser. This is Flex based technology (Action script + XML). It allows you creating standalone applications - we have 2 apps with AIR, but the AIR framework is slower then Java, it does not run on certain devices (low-end Androids), you must purchase the Adobe IDE and the developers base is smaller, so it is harder to find answers if you are in troubles. There is no clear advantage over Java, unless you plan to release also for desktop.

Regards,
STeN

Comment: Thanks!, looks like I will be diving into Android's animation library shortly :)

Comment: Hi ago - I was talking about the Flash in browser, but I added to my answer also section about AIR.